# Is this an acceptable 100Mhz OCXO output?

Tags: rf, oscillator, crystal

I was looking for a 100Mhz sinwave OCXO output.

I picked up a used one and I have the following output:
[image]

Each vertical square is 1 volt.

I was expecting it to look exactly like a mathematically plotted sine wave - are my expectations too high and this distortion at the extremities are to be expected in practice?

Even if it should be smoother and more like a sine wave will the leading edges still probably be enough for timing?

If I also ran this output through a power divider do you think the leading edge would be enough for timing (I know this probably quite vague unfortunately the documentation I have on the input pin requirements of the receiving chip is non-existent.

Comment: You should expect harmonics to be -40dB

Comment: there's oscillators that will produce sine waves, and others, which produced clipped sine waves or approximate square waves. don't know hwat you have!

Comment: You don’t give any specs or datasheet so why ask is it acceptable?

Comment: At this frequency, what you will see on the scope depends as much on the scope and probes and their adjustment as it does on the signal itself.  That said, this looks more like a square wave degraded by measurement technique than something intended to be a sine wave.  To judge the quality of a reference signal, a scope is hardly the right instrument to begin with, you really need to be looking in the frequency domain.

Comment: also, I had an argument with a guy for *weeks* that his scope wouldn't agree on the frequency that the GPS-disciplined OCXO-driven device I was supporting was supposed to produce. If you want to measure the frequency of something, you need a measurement device with a frequency standard that's orders better. If the thing you're observing is already an OCXO, bad news: scope's internal oscillator will be worse.

Comment: @[Tony EE rocketscientist] Well I am ignorant in this field but the datasheet for the chip I want to use states "The OSCin pins can be driven single-ended with a CMOS clock or XO" so I was wondering if what I had laying around would work and as that was all the details in the datasheet describing OSCin I was assuming there was some kind of standard on what the expected behavior from these devices were.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yeah my hardware sucks, but I had seen cleaner sine-wave output from other devices I had tested on it in the 300Mhz range. I could also be using the oscilloscope wrong :) but I set the channel to 50 Ohm and directly connected the output from the OCXO sma connector with a coax cable to the oscilloscope.

Comment: I don't think your equipment sucks! It's just that we don't know what your OCXO *should* be producing (hypothesis: square wave) and that we think it's the wing *type* of equipment. Also, you cannot even test the frequency correctness of an ocxo without much ado.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, unfortunately i do not have a spectrum analyzer

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be pure sinusoidal? This is a normal oscillator output, as many thousands of XO/OCXO/TXCO do. As a matter of fact, it is rather difficult to generate pure sinusoidal signal. More, the main function of any XO is to generate best "clock", and sharper edges obviously provide less jitter for input stages, so ideally you should expect a square wave with 50% duty cycle.

Comment: And what model scope are you using? What is your nominal bandwidth?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, and how exactly looking into "frequency domain" will be any better than looking at the scope trace?

Comment: Still no model?!

Comment: @AliChen - as anyone works with RF will explain, looking in the frequency domain will show the overtone content of the signal (ie, the distortion from a sine wave) much more accurately than a scope will.

Comment: The shape of the waveform is only relevant for jitter determination.  If you are using it as a reference for a disciplined oscillator it should be able to average out the jitter over time and lock onto the fundamental frequency.  If your device is expecting a square wave for clocking some sampling then jitter may be very important.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist its an old Tektronix 2465 300MHz

Comment: I meant the OCXO

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist it is a Wenzel Associates 5939-0114S +12VDC 100Mhz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable 100Mhz OCXO output?

Within the limitations of measuring it with an oscilloscope, yes, probably.

Amplitude

You want to use it as a clock for your circuit. You need therefore sufficient volts peak to peak, and fast and clean slew rate through the transition regions, which it shows. There's no real requirement to have any particular waveshape at the top and bottom, so the fact that it doesn't look precisely sine, or square, should not matter.

Frequency

Measuring a single cycle, or even a few, between cursors, any timing *on an oscilloscope* from 9.5nS to 10.5nS would be acceptable. It means the OCXO is not grossly wrong.

If you want to tell whether your OCXO is producing 100MHz +/- 1kHz, or +/- 10Hz, or +/- 0.1Hz, then you need different equipment.

Comment: I was actually able to put this signal through a power divider and have it act as the clock for 2 separate circuits. With the equipment I have I did not notice a difference between this clock and the ones already in the circuit.

Comment: “There’s no real requirements to have any particular waveshape” - actually there is. What about harmonics EMI? Depending on the circuit’s response to such phenomenon it can be affected by it

Answer (score 0):

The only web specs are ;

+13dBm sine

Detailed specs upon request,

This ought to be tuneable and stable to 1e-11 or 1Hz /100MHz or PLL synchronized to a GPS clock.

It is suitable to be filtered for analog purposes or to be biased for CML logic comparator as a digital clock.

This needs a suitable load resistance of 50 Ohms since it is specified in dBm to measure +13 dBm.

Answer (score -1):

Is this an acceptable output? Here is a bit of math.

Your edge is 1nanosecond, up and down. DeltaVoltage is 3.5 volts. Thus the slewrate is 3.5 volts per nanosecond.

Now we need to assume a noise density in your IC. Assume 1Kohm Rnoise referred to the input of your IC, the Vin_OSC pin.

Assume the noise bandwidth is 10 Gigahertz.

Given a noise density and noise bandwidth, we compute the total integrated noise as 4nanoVoltsrms/rootHz * sqrt(10,000,000,000) = 4nV * 100,000

or Total Referred To input Noise (of your IC that probably will square up the signal) is 4e-9 * 1e+5 = 4e-4 = 4 * 100microVolts rms = 400 microVolts rms.

Now we can compute the total integrated jitter as

Tj = Vnoise / SlewRate

Tj = 400 microVolts rms / 3.5 GigaVolts per second

The volts cancel (top and bottom have "volts") and we simply perform some scientific-notation division, thusly

Tj = 400 e-4 / 3.5 e+9

Tj ~~ 1e-4-9 = 1e-13 = 0.1 picosecond = 100 femtoSeconds RMS total integrated jitter

Spread over 10GigaHertz, the jitter per rootHz is 100fS/sqrt(10Giga)

Jitter per rootHz is 100fS / 100,000 = 1e-18 seconds per rootHz.

Can you do better? Sure. Place a 50_ohm Rnoise PreAmplifer Squaring circuit, perhaps simply a differential pair with Rnoise (the base rbb') of 50 ohms.
The noise density (that 4 nanoVolts rms, in the early paragraph) will drop by ratio of sqrt(1,000 ohms / 50 ohms) or sqrt(20) or 4.5. Your total integrated noise (assuming the same bandwidth of 10GigaHertz) will drop by 4.5x.
Your jitter will also drop by 4.5X. For your efforts, the jitter per rootHz will be 2 * 10^-19 seconds rms.

Comment: You must have a stalker after you. Every single answer you post is downvoted.